# Difference beetween search and Search elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

What difference between search and Search?

```js
>>> Search
<class 'elasticsearch_dsl.search.Search'>
```

```js
>>> search
<module 'elasticsearch_dsl.search' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/search.pyc'>
```

From `Search()` i got `elasticsearch_dsl.search.Search` object. And from `Elsasticsearch.search()` i got dict with elastic data. How can I got all(not first 5 objects) `elasticdata` from `Search()`? Can i make search object from `Search()` to got dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the data from elasticsearch in python use the `scan` helper by calling the `scan()` method on a `Search` object.

To get a `dict` instead of the wrapped object just call `to_dict()` on either the response directly or on every hit, if you want the metadata as well (things like `_id`, `_index` etc) call `to_dict(True)`.

Comment: OK, I got it. But I have really much data and `scan()` takes too much time to process it. Can u help me one more time, When i hit in for loop in my `Search` object i get only 10 elements. So i need to use `size`, how can i make something like `size='max'`?

Comment: The maximum allowed size is quite low, if you have a lot of data you need to use `scan` since it is optimized for that use case. It makes repeated requests to gradually fetch all of your data so it allows for stream processing - you don't have to wait for it to finish to start processing the data...